# MongoDB – Slow text search query with multiple words on a large dataset

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas

I have a M10 Atlas instance.

The issue happens in a DB with **2.5m** of documents, but only **900k** of `{ status: "active" }` ones.

The search is **quick when no sorting/projection is performed**, but in order to show the most accurate results first, it needs to be done otherwise the results are a mess.

For some reason this text search is being very slow for medium/long phrases and I have no idea how to speed it up.

Having the following document:

```
{
  _id: "FOO123",
  track_date: { $date: "2019-03-09T05:49:22.000Z" },
  category_id: "foo",
  parent_category_id: "foo",
  title: "Disco Ssd Solido Kingston 480g Macbook Pro Air iMac Martinez",
  status: "active",
  site_id: "foo",
  seller_id: 9999,
  price: 9999,
  permalink:
    "https://example.com",
  secure_thumbnail:
    "https://example.com/img.jpg",
  images: [
    "https://example.com/img.jpg",
  ],
  fluctuation: 80,
  last_update: { $date: "2020-12-11T14:00:24.715Z" },
  original_price: null,
}
```

Performing the following query:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "status": "active",
      "site_id": "foo",
      "$text": {
        "$search": "Disco Ssd solido kingston 480g macbook pro air",
        "$caseSensitive": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "score": {
        "$meta": "textScore"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
])
```

Takes around **35s** to yield results.

---

These are the indexes that I have set up for the `active` and `title` fields *(I also have compound indexes that mix these two and a few more properties, I can show them here if needed)*

```
{
  v: 2,
  key: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
  name: "title_text",
  language_override: "language",
  weights: { title: 1 },
  default_language: "english",
  ns: "foo.articles",
  textIndexVersion: 3,
},
{
  v: 2,
  key: { status: 1 },
  name: "status_1",
  ns: "foo.articles",
}
```

---

This is the result of `explain("executionStats")`

Query (as aggregation did not work with `"executionStats"`:

```
collection.find(
    {
      status: "active",
      site_id: "foo",
      $text: {
        $search: "Disco Ssd solido kingston 480g macbook pro air",
        $caseSensitive: false,
      },
    },
    { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
  )
  .sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
  .skip(0)
  .limit(10)
  .explain("executionStats")
```

Explain with execution stats:

```
{
  queryPlanner: {
    plannerVersion: 1,
    namespace: "foo.articles",
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: {
      $and: [
        { site_id: { $eq: "foo" } },
        { status: { $eq: "active" } },
        {
          $text: {
            $search: "Disco Ssd solido kingston 480g macbook pro air",
            $language: "english",
            $caseSensitive: false,
            $diacriticSensitive: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    winningPlan: {
      stage: "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
      transformBy: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } },
      inputStage: {
        stage: "SORT",
        sortPattern: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } },
        limitAmount: 10,
        inputStage: {
          stage: "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
          inputStage: {
            stage: "FETCH",
            filter: {
              $and: [
                { site_id: { $eq: "foo" } },
                { status: { $eq: "active" } },
              ],
            },
            inputStage: {
              stage: "TEXT",
              indexPrefix: {},
              indexName: "title_text",
              parsedTextQuery: {
                terms: [
                  "480g",
                  "air",
                  "disco",
                  "kingston",
                  "macbook",
                  "pro",
                  "solido",
                  "ssd",
                ],
                negatedTerms: [],
                phrases: [],
                negatedPhrases: [],
              },
              textIndexVersion: 3,
              inputStage: {
                stage: "TEXT_MATCH",
                inputStage: {
                  stage: "TEXT_OR",
                  inputStages: [
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    rejectedPlans: [],
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 10,
    executionTimeMillis: 30458,
    totalKeysExamined: 169654,
    totalDocsExamined: 279454,
    executionStages: {
      stage: "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
      nReturned: 10,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 27307,
      works: 309403,
      advanced: 10,
      needTime: 309392,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 3211,
      restoreState: 3211,
      isEOF: 1,
      transformBy: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } },
      inputStage: {
        stage: "SORT",
        nReturned: 10,
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: 27299,
        works: 309403,
        advanced: 10,
        needTime: 309392,
        needYield: 0,
        saveState: 3211,
        restoreState: 3211,
        isEOF: 1,
        sortPattern: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } },
        memUsage: 9275,
        memLimit: 33554432,
        limitAmount: 10,
        inputStage: {
          stage: "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
          nReturned: 31606,
          executionTimeMillisEstimate: 27262,
          works: 309392,
          advanced: 31606,
          needTime: 277785,
          needYield: 0,
          saveState: 3211,
          restoreState: 3211,
          isEOF: 1,
          inputStage: {
            stage: "FETCH",
            filter: {
              $and: [
                { site_id: { $eq: "foo" } },
                { status: { $eq: "active" } },
              ],
            },
            nReturned: 31606,
            executionTimeMillisEstimate: 27251,
            works: 309391,
            advanced: 31606,
            needTime: 277784,
            needYield: 0,
            saveState: 3211,
            restoreState: 3211,
            isEOF: 1,
            docsExamined: 139727,
            alreadyHasObj: 139727,
            inputStage: {
              stage: "TEXT",
              nReturned: 139727,
              executionTimeMillisEstimate: 27191,
              works: 309391,
              advanced: 139727,
              needTime: 169663,
              needYield: 0,
              saveState: 3211,
              restoreState: 3211,
              isEOF: 1,
              indexPrefix: {},
              indexName: "title_text",
              parsedTextQuery: {
                terms: [
                  "480g",
                  "air",
                  "disco",
                  "kingston",
                  "macbook",
                  "pro",
                  "solido",
                  "ssd",
                ],
                negatedTerms: [],
                phrases: [],
                negatedPhrases: [],
              },
              textIndexVersion: 3,
              inputStage: {
                stage: "TEXT_MATCH",
                nReturned: 139727,
                executionTimeMillisEstimate: 27191,
                works: 309391,
                advanced: 139727,
                needTime: 169663,
                needYield: 0,
                saveState: 3211,
                restoreState: 3211,
                isEOF: 1,
                docsRejected: 0,
                inputStage: {
                  stage: "TEXT_OR",
                  nReturned: 139727,
                  executionTimeMillisEstimate: 27191,
                  works: 309391,
                  advanced: 139727,
                  needTime: 169663,
                  needYield: 0,
                  saveState: 3211,
                  restoreState: 3211,
                  isEOF: 1,
                  docsExamined: 139727,
                  inputStages: [
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      nReturned: 291,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
                      works: 292,
                      advanced: 291,
                      needTime: 0,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 3211,
                      restoreState: 3211,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                      keysExamined: 291,
                      seeks: 1,
                      dupsTested: 291,
                      dupsDropped: 0,
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      nReturned: 26973,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 121,
                      works: 26974,
                      advanced: 26973,
                      needTime: 0,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 3211,
                      restoreState: 3211,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                      keysExamined: 26973,
                      seeks: 1,
                      dupsTested: 26973,
                      dupsDropped: 0,
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      nReturned: 29687,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 69,
                      works: 29688,
                      advanced: 29687,
                      needTime: 0,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 3211,
                      restoreState: 3211,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                      keysExamined: 29687,
                      seeks: 1,
                      dupsTested: 29687,
                      dupsDropped: 0,
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      nReturned: 13595,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 28,
                      works: 13596,
                      advanced: 13595,
                      needTime: 0,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 3211,
                      restoreState: 3211,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                      keysExamined: 13595,
                      seeks: 1,
                      dupsTested: 13595,
                      dupsDropped: 0,
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      nReturned: 10730,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 28,
                      works: 10731,
                      advanced: 10730,
                      needTime: 0,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 3211,
                      restoreState: 3211,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                      keysExamined: 10730,
                      seeks: 1,
                      dupsTested: 10730,
                      dupsDropped: 0,
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      nReturned: 53358,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 248,
                      works: 53359,
                      advanced: 53358,
                      needTime: 0,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 3211,
                      restoreState: 3211,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                      keysExamined: 53358,
                      seeks: 1,
                      dupsTested: 53358,
                      dupsDropped: 0,
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      nReturned: 7847,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 13,
                      works: 7848,
                      advanced: 7847,
                      needTime: 0,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 3211,
                      restoreState: 3211,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                      keysExamined: 7847,
                      seeks: 1,
                      dupsTested: 7847,
                      dupsDropped: 0,
                    },
                    {
                      stage: "IXSCAN",
                      nReturned: 27173,
                      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 17,
                      works: 27174,
                      advanced: 27173,
                      needTime: 0,
                      needYield: 0,
                      saveState: 3211,
                      restoreState: 3211,
                      isEOF: 1,
                      keyPattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 },
                      indexName: "title_text",
                      isMultiKey: true,
                      isUnique: false,
                      isSparse: false,
                      isPartial: false,
                      indexVersion: 2,
                      direction: "backward",
                      indexBounds: {},
                      keysExamined: 27173,
                      seeks: 1,
                      dupsTested: 27173,
                      dupsDropped: 0,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  serverInfo: {
    host: "host",
    port: "port",
    version: "4.2.11",
    gitVersion: "ea38428f0c6742c7c2c7f677e73d79e17a2aab96",
  },
  ok: 1,
  $clusterTime: {
    clusterTime: Timestamp(1, 1609902178),
    signature: {
      hash: BinData(0, "cunb+7FEjXmbwN22uz3F+nV0LKE="),
      keyId: NumberLong("6911938552179720195"),
    },
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp(1, 1609902178),
}
```

---

The issue is not related to the `status` field, as I've tried removing it and the issue persists.
I don't really mind a query that's a bit slow, but more than half a minute is too much for a search.

At first I was doing an AND query for the text search instead of an OR, but it was even slower for long phrases, so decided to give the `score` a try.
I've also tried removing the sort pipeline, but it still takes 30s~

I'll take any tip anyone can give me at this point.

**EDIT:** According to the explain("executionStats") bit, it seems that the sort/projection of score is the time sink, but I've no idea how to improve that in order to get the best matches first

Comment: maybe compound index on status + site_id can be of help here ...

Comment: @kiko075 I can try that, do you think it would lower the times considerably?

Comment: It depends on selectivity of those fields , if 900k are active , how much from those 900k are with site_id:"foo" ?

Comment: @kiko075 around 890k, so most of them

Comment: In that case no sense to do it ...  , it seems your time consumption mostly in the full  text search stage , btw can you provide results from  explain("executionStats") ?

Comment: @kiko075 I just edited the question with the `explain("executionStatus")` result, although I don't see any differences from the common `explain()`

Comment: Indeed forgot it  is aggregation , but you can run same query with find().explain("executionStats") , also since you are using atlas , have you tested to create inverse index (atlas search) for your full text search functionality it is expected to be way better then the usual mongodb text search index?

Comment: @kiko075 Trying to refactor to use `.find()` I noticed that if I remove the sort (and use find instead of aggregation) it lowers the time considerably to around 3s. Updated the question with the result of execution stats

Comment: it seems like the status index is not used, can you force status index with hint: db.collection.find().hint( { status: 1 } )

Comment: @kiko075 getting `MongoError: text and hint not allowed in same query` for that

Comment: or maybe compound index status + title...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226942/discussion-between-gmaiolo-and-kiko075).

Comment: Few more things:  1) Increase vCPU ?  2) Increase cacheSizeGB ? 3) Index re-build if db is often updated/deleted? 4) when $skip is big value this always affect execution time since earlier reconrds are always read before skipped ...

Comment: @R2D2 for 1) and 2) I rather be sure that it's a vCPU or RAM issue and there's no way of me fixing it as it is right now because upgrading either of those means a lot of extra $ in Atlas. 3) The DB tends to get several docs updates and additions but never deletes, I've already rebuilt indexes a few times trying things out as well. 4) Haven't even tried with a skip higher than 0!

Comment: cacheSizeGB ( Do the indexes fit in RAM  and is there space for working set) ?

Comment: @R2D2 The M10 instance has 2GB RAM and indexes are around 700mb, I assume the working set space is around 1.3gb, but I'm not sure

Comment: and the database size? 2GB very small and the cpu?

Comment: The database size is around 2GB

Comment: Sorry @R2D2 I just ran the stats correctly and the total data size is `3.4GB` and the index size is `1.38GB`

Comment: as suspected you need RAM...

Comment: Would 4gb be enough @R2D2 ?

Comment: 4GB is afcourse much better...

Comment: how about the cpu?

Comment: I'm trying to find the power of the 2 vCPUs from Atlas M10 cluster tier but can't find any info, I doubt they're powerful though

Comment: You're sorting a whole bunch of document, which is very ram costly, suggest you to project only the _id of the document and the meta textscore before doing the sort.
Then once you have you result, do another query to retrieve the documents

Comment: I don't see in the aggregate pipeline that the text-find is specifically targeting the Title field.  But I notice the sample provided is from a Title field.....  just a sanity check comment ....Is it your intention to search the entire document or just the Title field?

Comment: did you try to leverage _short-circuit evaluation_ by trying to split the `$match` to include the first 2 indexed (status and site_id) first so they can benefit from the index, and then evaluate the remaining records ($text) ? I.e.: using `$and`

Comment: @Simon *The $match stage that includes a $text must be the first stage in the pipeline.* and the rest of limitations can be learned from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-query-operator-behavior

Comment: @Daphoque that's an interesting suggestion, I'll give it a try

Comment: @CahabaData as far as I understand, the scope of the text search in mongo is defined by the index, and as the index is specifying that the title is the only property in the scope it will only search in that field

Answer (score 2):

**Mongodb Atlas specific feature**

Since you are using Atlas you may find https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search a better alternative. It uses Lucene engine similar to Elasticsearch, Solr, etc, instead of rather limited native text index which is available on self-hosted versions of the database.

Atlas search is way more flexible and in most cases faster than mongo text index. The downside is a noticeable lag (like very eventual consistency), and higher demand on disk space (especially for ngram tokenizers) but these are not critical in your case.

The search is available on clusters of v4.2+:
[image]

Give it a try, it's included in your subscription.

The highlighted parts of the question must be confusing and are deserved some explanations:

> The issue happens in a DB with 2.5m of documents, but only 900k of { status: "active" } ones.

It doesn't really matter how many active documents there are. There is no index intersection so the only text index is used. Filter by status and site_id is done only on the FETCH stage. In other words you search all 2.5m documents regardless of other filters.

> The search is quick when no sorting/projection is performed

$sort is a blocking stage, means it requires previous stage to complete. You have $skip-$limit stages to return 10 documents only. Without $sort stage the pipeline returns 10 documents that were found first. With $sort stage the pipeline waits for all documents to be searched to find 10 with highest score.

> For some reason this text search is being very slow for medium/long phrases

The reason is obvious - the more words in the phrase the more searches mongo need to do. It's one search per word, then calculation of the score based on the results of all searches.

Memory shouldn't be an issue for the sorting stage. The limit is 100 MB, then it starts using disk regardless of how much RAM you have.

Lack of memory might be a problem if all indexes and the working set don't fit into RAM. If it is the case it should be highlighted in the "Performance Advisor" tab.
`db.collection.totalIndexSize()` can also give you some idea of how much RAM you would need for optimal performance. It is not specific to the text index and affects performance of the whole cluster.